# Load comments in wordpress template for a specific post

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

Hi I use this code to load the content and info of a specific post:

```
if ($actual_link == $wpbase){
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts('1');
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<article id="post-'.$recent["ID"].'"><h1>' .
                $recent["post_title"] .
            '</h1>' .
            apply_filters('the_content', $recent["post_comments"]) .
        '</article><aside>' .
            $recent["post_content"].
        '</aside>';
    };
}
```

but somehow the last expression `$recent["post_comments"]` does not return anything. not even raw comment text. Am I doing something wrong? I tried diffent syntaxes, also using `wp_list_comments( $args );` but never got it really working.

Any ideas how to get this working?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`wp_get_recent_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) does not return post comments, take a look at [`get_post` return value](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post#Return) to see available fields.

[`wp_list_comments`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) will display a list of comments, but you should use it inside a [wordpress loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

But you can use [get_comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) to get an array of comments, take a look at examples on codex.

PS: the way you are using `wp_get_recent_posts` is deprecated, you should use an array instead of `'1'`

Comment: thanks I will take a look at it. how would I write that down as an array? :s